# How can I create an autoload file for PHP code generated by Swagger Code Generator?

Tags: php, autoload, swagger-codegen, openapi

I've used the Swagger Code Generator (to be exact, the updated version which is compatible with OpenApi 3.0.0 named [openapi-generator-cli](http://openapi-generator.tech/)) to generate some PHP code from an *OpenAPI.yaml* file.

The code generation did work, but I'm missing the autoload to use the generated code. How can I generate that autoload file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generated files don't include the vendor folder which contains the dependencies stated in the composer.json file. To isntall them, just do `composer install` in the root directory of your generated package. If you don't have composer installed in your $PATH variable, have a look [the composer docs to install it properly](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md). Then you can just `require_once('/path/to/OpenAPIClient-php/vendor/autoload.php');` and be on your way.